# Who was D.A. Millin, the eponym of the Millin Series?

Tags: biographical-details

The **Millin series** is defined as:

$$\sum_{n \mathop = 0}^\infty \frac 1 {F_{2^n} }$$

where $F_n$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number.

It can be shown to equal $\dfrac {7 - \sqrt 5} 2$.

But who was the D.A. Millin who it is named after?

**EDIT**: User https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/16591/michael has located the issue of FQ in which Millin's name originally appears, where he was identified as a Pennsylvanian high-school student in 1974.

Further to this, I have found that the solution appeared in FQ issue Vol. 14 no. 2 (1976), but in this case his name appears as **D.A. Miller**.

The question arises as to whether **Millin** might have been a misprint. If his name truly *is* "Miller", then his precise identity may be very difficult to track down. There is a professor in Virginia with that name, but he appears a couple of decades too young.

Whoever he is, he may well be currently active.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am the author of the Advanced Problem H-237 to the FQ issue Vol. 14 no. 2 (1976).  The series in that Problem was later named the Millin series.  At that time, I was a senior at the Annville-Cleona High School in Pennsylvania.  This series was also part of the paper titled "Observations in Pure Mathematics" that I submitted to the 1974 Westinghouse Science Talent Search (now the Regeneron Science Talent Search).  In the days before LaTeX, I wrote my submission to FQ using a combination of handwriting and a typewriter.  Apparently, my handwritten signature was not clear and was misread at the time.

Frankly, I like the name "the Millin Series," and I hope no one makes an effort to change it.  For my proof of this identity, see the last entry on this [webpage](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Dale.Miller/papers/pubs.html)

[Dale A Miller, Research Scientist, Inria, France](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Dale.Miller/)

Answer (score 14):

The furthest back I came is [this 1974 article](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/12-3/advanced12-3.pdf) from The Fibonacci Quarterly 12, No. 3.

Extract:
[image]